# Android Studio 3.6 canary 4 - Gradle throwing DefaultProjectSyncIssues exception

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jdk

I updated Android Studio 3.6 Canary 3 to 3.6 Canary 4 few hours ago, and just moments ago I tried to open a project, but it didn't even configure when I opened the project.

I already had *Gradle 3.6.0-alpha04* before updating to 3.6C4**

Why is Gradle throwing this exception?

To me, it looks like there's something wrong with its code... but I'm not sure.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.DefaultProjectSyncIssues
> com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.DefaultProjectSyncIssues

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 20s
Cause: com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.DefaultProjectSyncIssues
ERROR: Cause: com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.DefaultProjectSyncIssues
```

Is there a solution?

---

#### I changed back to *AS 3.6 Canary 3* because it works

Comment: This is more like a http://stackoverflow.com/ question

Comment: @AlexBurdusel yes, but i thought problems related to softwares and their crashes and troubleshooting would be appropriate in Superuser

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just upgrade your Android Gradle plugin manually to alpha 4.

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0-alpha04'`

Comment: i already had that version before updating, and i even invalidated cache and deleted every folder related to Gradle and Android Studio, but nothing worked

Comment: @TheBadak - You're updating in the project build.gradle? This worked for me!

Comment: @AjahnCharles i created a new project and it didn't show any error
no idea what happened, but welp at least it's working

Comment: @TheBadak - Welcome to Canary ;)

Comment: @AjahnCharles lol thanks man, i was on canary before, years later i switched to beta, then back to stable and now again on canary 

Comment: Great answer, thx

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue, and updating my Gradle build tools version did the trick:

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0-alpha04'

Comment: i already had that version before updating, and i even invalidated cache and deleted every folder related to Gradle and Android Studio, but nothing worked